# Jlabel show on row correctly

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I have a jlabel to show text with multiple lines. When run, the text does not look like my expect. it is not in the same line with another jlabel.
Here is my code:

```
String test="<html> Most of us switch the system on and off as we require; we expect lots of heat and hot water 365 days a year </html>";

JLabel lblCompleDescr = new JLabel();
lblCompleDescr.setFont((new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)));
lblCompleDescr.setText(test);
this.add(lblCompleDescr, new GridBagConstraints(0, POS_Y, 1, 1,
                1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                new Insets(0, GUIConstants.ELM_FIRST_COLUMN_WIDTH+10 , 0,
                        GUIConstants.ELM_ALIGN_RIGHT), 240, 0));
```

This is result:

[image]

Please help me review it. Thanks

Comment: What kind of layout has you parent panel? I advise a `GridBagLayout();`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using absolute layout for parent container, in cases like this i.e,  when we have to make different adjustments for different components. And then make use of `setBounds()` or `setSize()` . Something like `lblCompleDescr.setSize()`